# Null Pointer Exception when creating new model or reimport a model

Tags: java, eclipse, webdynpro

I'm trying to create or import a model, I find this error below.

I am using SAP NetWeaver Developer Studio 7.0, apparently there is some incompatibility of some java plug-in for this platform to be run on Windows 7.

Any help!?

> ```
> An internal error has ocurred. See error log for more details.
> Plugin name: Web Dynpro Model Editor
> Plugin ID: com.sap.ide.webdynpro.modeleditor
> Class: com.sap.ide.webdynpro.modeleditor.ModelEditorCallback
> Method: ReimportModel
> Message: An internal error has ocurred. See error log for more details.
> Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Null pointer Exception throws when some variable doesn't have any initial values. Restart the application may force the program work fine.

Pls refer the link

[Solution for the similar issue](http://scn.sap.com/thread/786605)

Comment: The Null Pointer Exception may be caused by many situations and do not necessarily have to be in code. In the absence of allocated memory needed to use a resource, or any tool can also be provoked.

Answer (score 1):

And yes Dhivya, yesterday I found this link that solves the problem.

http://scn.sap.com/thread/786605

By using a different operating system than Win XP, we must look to the NetWeaver Eclipse folder, a file called vm.parameters.

C:\Program Files\SAP\IDE\IDE70\eclipse

and add the following line.

-Dos.name='Windows XP'

and ready to resolve the problem.